# Banach spaces with unconditional basis have w-FPP

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

A Banach space $X$ is said to have **w-FPP** *(weak fixed point property)* if for every non-empty, weakly compact and convex subset $K\subseteq X$; every non-expansing mapping $T:K\longmapsto K$ i.e.

$$\|Tx-Ty\|\leq \|x-y\|\quad\quad \forall\, x,y \in K$$

has a fixed point.

Recall that if $X$ has an unconditional basis $(e_i)$, the *constant of unconditionality* $\lambda$ is

\begin{align}
\lambda:=&\sup\lbrace \|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \epsilon_i\zeta_i e_i\| \;\; : \;\; \|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \zeta_i e_i \|=1\, , \, \epsilon_i=\pm 1\rbrace \\
=& \sup\lbrace \|2P_F-I\|\;\;:\;\; F\subset\mathbb{N}\rbrace
\end{align}

where $P_F$ are the standard projections onto a finite subset $F$.

Suppose $X$ has constant of unconditionality $\lambda$. [Lin](https://msp.org/pjm/1985/116-1/pjm-v116-n1-p07-s.pdf)<sup>1</sup> proved via ultraproduct constructions that if $\lambda<\frac{\sqrt{33}-3}{2}$ then $X$ has the w-FPP. This raises the question whether every Banach space with unconditional basis enjoys the w-FPP.

My questions are the following:

1. Has this result been improved in any direction? For instance, with further assumptions can the bound be improved? Do you know any references?
2. Are there any other approaches to tackle this problem?

Actually any reference or idea on how to proceed would help.

<sup>1</sup>Lin, Pei-Kee. Unconditional bases and fixed points of nonexpansive mappings. Pacific J. Math. 116 (1985), no. 1, 69--76; 
[MR769823](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=769823), 
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102707248,
http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1985.116.69

Comment: Posted also on math.SE: [Banach spaces with unconditional basis have w-FPP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569982)

Comment: Is there any example of a weakly compact convex set that fails the fixed point property that is essentially different from Alspach's example?

Comment: @BillJohnson As far as I know, there are very sparse examples of weakly compact convex sets failing fpp. All of which are variants or modifications of Aslpach's example. See, for example section 4 of https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-017-1748-9_2